# How to use GSAP bonus plugins in Nuxt.js?

Tags: nuxt.js, gsap

I used  https://github.com/nuxt-community/starter-template for a fresh local install. My dependencies are **gsap 2.0.1** and **nuxt 1.0.0**.

*What I tried so far to get the bonus plugins running in Nuxt:*

#### 1 - All bonus files in node_modules & import via page file (not working)

I downloaded the package **bonus-files-for-npm-users** and put all files in **node_modules/gsap/**.

In my page file **index.vue** I referenced GSAP like this:

```js
import { TweenMax } from 'gsap'; 
import { MorphSVGPlugin } from 'gsap/MorphSVGPlugin';
// I also tried:
// import MorphSVGPlugin from 'gsap/MorphSVGPlugin';
```

TweenMax is running without problems, but the plugin does not:

```js
S:\Vue\myPath\node_modules\gsap\MorphSVGPlugin.js:14
import { _gsScope } from "gsap/TweenLite.js";
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

#### 2 - All bonus files in a root folder & import Tweenmax via page file & import bonus plugin via nuxt.config.js (not working)

I moved all bonus plugin files to a root directory **/gsap**. I keep the import of TweenMax in my page file, as it was working without problems. In my **nuxt.config.js** I tried the following config I found broadly similar in other projects:

```js
    build: {
        extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
            if (isDev && isClient) {
                config.module.rules.push({
                    enforce: 'pre',
                    test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
                    loader: 'eslint-loader',
                    exclude: /(node_modules)/
                })
            };
            if (isClient) {
                config.entry.app.push('gsap', '/gsap/MorphSVGPlugin');
                // I also tried:
                // config.entry.app.push('gsap', '~/gsap/MorphSVGPlugin');
            };
        }
    }
```

#### 3 - All bonus files in static folder & import Tweenmax via page file & import bonus plugin via nuxt.config.js (working, but only for ONE bonus plugin)

I moved all bonus plugins to to **/static/gsap/**. Hooray! My bonus plugin is working now. With the following configuration in **nuxt.config.js**:

```js
build: {
    extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
        if (isDev && isClient) {
            config.module.rules.push({
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/
            })
        };
        if (isClient) {
            config.entry.app.push('gsap', '~/static/gsap/MorphSVGPlugin');
        };
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I only get one bonus plugin working like this. This is not working:

```js
build: {
    extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
        if (isDev && isClient) {
            config.module.rules.push({
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/
            })
        };
        if (isClient) {
            config.entry.app.push('gsap', '~/static/gsap/MorphSVGPlugin');
            config.entry.app.push('gsap', '~/static/gsap/SplitText');
            config.entry.app.push('gsap', '~/static/gsap/DrawSVGPlugin');
            config.entry.app.push('gsap', '~/static/gsap/GSDevTools');
        };
    }
}
```

My question is: 
**How do I get several GSAP bonus plugins working in Nuxt.js?**

Comment: I found the config.entry.app.push() method in a GSAP discussion thread:
https://greensock.com/forums/topic/17888-importing-plugins-in-nuxtjs/
The method I found in Sarah Drasners famous nuxt-type was not working for me: https://github.com/sdras/nuxt-type/blob/master/nuxt.config.js

Answer (score 1):

Compromise solution: I got it running when using static resouces only.

```js
script: [
  { src: 'gsap/TweenMax.min.js' },
  { src: 'gsap/MorphSVGPlugin.min.js' },
  { src: 'gsap/SplitText.min.js' },
  { src: 'gsap/DrawSVGPlugin.min.js' },
  { src: 'gsap/GSDevTools.min.js' }
]
```

But I would really like to find out how to use GSAP bonus plugins  with **node_modules** and a regular build process.

Comment: Cross referencing GSAP forum:
https://greensock.com/forums/topic/17888-importing-plugins-in-nuxtjs/

Answer (score 0):

Create a plugin gsap.js:

```
import gsap from 'gsap'

if (process.client) {
  gsap.registerPlugin()
}
```

Import the plugin in your nuxt.config, normally.

That's it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But the question is about **gsap 2.0.1** with **nuxt 1.0.0**. See the intro about dependencies.

Comment: Did you try it? it worked perfectly for me, I'm just saying...

Comment: But the method registerPlugin() was introduced in 3.x. It didn't even exist in 2.x, or am I wrong here? Did you have a look at the discussion (https://greensock.com/forums/topic/17888-importing-plugins-in-nuxtjs/)? No, I have not tried again, I switched to v3. I will try to find the time.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else coming here from Google. The ZIP from GreenSock now includes `src/bonus-files-for-npm-users/umd/CustomEase.js` which you can put inside a local folder, and import that inside a Vue component.

```js
import CustomEase from "../vendor/gsap/CustomEase";
```

And now works as intended.

Comment: This question is about Nuxt, not a general vue component, though. Can you shed some light on how to get this working in Nuxt? I tried with the new ZIP today, importing them in page files. But still no luck. I get dependency errors in the build process.

Comment: I believe he is suggesting you add to the "assets" folder and then reference them there. The result is similar to your compromise but rather than grab them from gsap you can include them directly in your project.